# How to connect to specific squema with python3 and postgres?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I want to connect to a postgres database in a specific squema using psycopg2. I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812463/setting-schema-for-all-queries-of-a-connection-in-psycopg2-getting-race-conditi) but I get a syntax error.

```
schema = conf['schema']
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname=conf['database'],
    user=conf['user'],
    host=conf['host'],
    password=conf['passw'],
    port=conf['port'],
    options=f'-c search_path={schema}',
)
```

I checked the config.json where I get the data.

Thanks

Comment: It might be the comma `,` after `options=f'-c search_path={schema}','`

Comment: tried before, did't work

Comment: ...What is a "squema"? A SQL schema?

Comment: @Q.Holness a postgres schema

Comment: Have you populated the json? 
Try to do the connection without using it by doing `dbname='mytable', user='myuser' ` just to make sure what it is.

Comment: @jalazbe tried too. The syntax error is in the line for options=f'......' but I don't where the problem is

Comment: Could you post anonimized information of your `conf['schema']` ? the problem might be ther .

Comment: can you share more about error?