# How to specified postgres schema in the function of copy_from?

Tags: python, postgresql, schema, psycopg2

I am trying to use the function of copy_from in psycopy2 to insert data to my table named "ST_DAY_SRS",but how can I specified the schema named "NEW_CNYB"? I used the parmeter of option but it doesnot work ,please help me,thanks very much.

```
def action():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host='****',port='45432',
                user='postgres',password='postgres',database='NEW_CNYB',options='-c search_path="NEW_CNYB"')

    df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['ID', 'DATE', 'SUNRISE', 'SUNSET'])
    ret=''
    values_list=[]

    for i in df.itertuples():
        values_list.append('\t'.join([i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4]]))
    for value in values_list:
        ret += value + '\n'
    print(ret)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.copy_from(file=io.StringIO(ret),table="ST_DAY_SRS",
                 columns=("ID", "DATE", "SUNRISE", "SUNSET"))
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `copy_expert()` instead of `copy_from()`

Example having a CSV file called `file`:

```
sql = "COPY SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER E'\\t')"

database_cursor.copy_expert(sql, file)
```

Answer (score -1):

The way i would do it, is to insert the schema_name before the table name like this

```
   # schema_name.table_name 
    cur.copy_from(file=io.StringIO(ret),table="ST_DAY_SRS",
                     columns=("ID", "DATE", "SUNRISE", "SUNSET"))
```

Another possibilities if that did not work out :

1. Set the schema for all the queries. [Check the replays on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812463/setting-schema-for-all-queries-of-a-connection-in-psycopg2-getting-race-conditi)
2. Create a role/user that belong to the schema instead with insert.

Good luck.

Comment: This code is exactly the same as in the question?